# Why does compilation not fail when a member of a moved value is assigned to?

Tags: rust

I am working through examples in [Rust by Example](http://rustbyexample.com/).

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Rectangle {
    p1: Point,
    p2: Point,
}

fn main() {
    let mut point: Point = Point { x: 0.3, y: 0.4 };
    println!("point coordinates: ({}, {})", point.x, point.y);

    let rectangle = Rectangle {
        p1: Point { x: 1.0, y: 1.0 },
        p2: point,
    };

    point.x = 0.5; // Why does the compiler not break here,
    println!(" x is {}", point.x); // but it breaks here?

    println!("rectangle is {:?} ", rectangle);
}
```

I get this error (Rust 1.25.0):

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `point.x`
  --> src/main.rs:23:26
   |
19 |         p2: point,
   |             ----- value moved here
...
23 |     println!(" x is {}", point.x);
   |                          ^^^^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `point` has type `Point`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I understand that I gave `point` to the `Rectangle` object and that is why I can no longer access it, but why does the compilation fail on the `println!` and not the assignment on the previous line?

Comment: [A smaller reproduction](http://is.gd/j8aovB).

Comment: I guess "using a moved value" can be interpreted as the point at which you try and read the value of it. Assigning to it doesn't really change the guarantees of Rust in a "technical" sense, only when you try and consume a moved value. That said, I don't understand most of this well enough myself so I am interested to hear from people who are more across this.

Comment: Feels like compiller bug. More interesting thing is that `let p2 = point;
    point.x = 0.5;
    println!(" x is {}", p2.x);` compiles fine and prints 0.3, so `point.x = 0.5;` does nothng

Comment: @qthree That's entirely to be expected; Rust uses value types, not reference types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What really happens

```
fn main() {
    let mut point: Point = Point { x: 0.3, y: 0.4 };
    println!("point coordinates: ({}, {})", point.x, point.y);

    drop(point);

    {
        let mut point: Point;
        point.x = 0.5;
    }

    println!(" x is {}", point.x);
}
```

It turns out that it's already known as [issue #21232](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21232).

Comment: Why do you have another `let mut point` within the nested block? Doesn't that change the problem because the point you're assigning to is a new point, in a different place in memory from the one that was dropped?

Comment: @AlexKnauth I think the idea is to point out whats happening as the compiler sees it. That is, that the compiler sees that extra scope there with its own "point" which is allowing the assignment.

Comment: Because `point.x = 0.5;` in original code does nothing with moved value, but tries to initialize new value.

Comment: But in the original code that scope wasn't there, and it didn't create a new `point` variable, but assigned to the old dropped `point`. Or am I misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: @AlexKnauth You're correct in that it wasn't there in the original code. I think qthree's intent here is to show what the compiler sees.. the compiler sees the OP's code as if this extra scope was there. Which is why the assignment works, but the `println!` line doesn't.

Comment: @AlexKnauth Old dropped point already moved and can't be accessed, the issue is that compiler allow partly initialize new value with old name, but even if you assign all fields it's still will not be fully initialized and in same time will be out of scope.

Comment: @qthree Your explanation is wrong. The `let mut point` inside a nested scope creates another `Point` variable somewhere else, and its scope ends before the `println!`, which is different from the OPs code. The real issue is just the compiler bug / misfeature described in https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21232 .

Comment: @qthree: Rust allows shadowing in the same scope; so to be less confusing I would simply remove the extra scope.

Comment: @MatthieuM. then you will get `use of possibly uninitialized variable: 'point.x'`. That bug is especially about trying partly initialize new value, while keeping old moved value in scope.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the compiler allows partial reinitialization of a struct, but the whole struct is unusable after that. This happens even if the struct contains only a single field, and even if you only try to read the field you just reinitialized.

```
struct Test {
    f: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut t = Test { f: 0 };
    let t1 = t;
    t.f = 1;
    println!("{}", t.f);
}
```

This is discussed in [issue 21232](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21232)

Comment: I'm unclear on what this answer provides beyond [the existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36051503/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster It removes the part that is wrong. As a bonus I added a brief explanation of the issue, as just posting a link is bad form.