# Compiler not happy with reading from dropped struct's field after writing to it

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {
    x: i32
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = A{x: 1};
    drop(x);
    // this is fine?
    x.x = 100;
    // this is not? ERROR: "use of moved value x.x"
    println!("{}", x.x);
}
```

I've read some answers here that says if you re-initialize the struct after move, then you can use it again. I am re-initializing it fully here and yet can't use it. Why is this feature (ability to write to struct fields after move) even there?

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question to expand on why it's not a duplicate of [Why does compilation not fail when a member of a moved value is assigned to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36048741/155423) and/or [Why is assigning to a member of a pointer still valid after the pointer is moved?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46833271/155423)

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that first question. Looks a harmless bug it seems. Feel free to mark this as duplicate and thanks.