# Why does Rust allow modification of a mutable struct after moving it into a closure?

Tags: rust, closures, borrow-checker

What makes the following piece of code able to compile?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Abc {
    x: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut n = Abc { x: 20 };
    let c = &move || {
        println!("{:?}", n);
    };

    (*c)();
    n.x = 12; //-> But n is moved??
}
```

Comment: The closure has nothing to do with it. I believe this question to already be answered by [Why does compilation not fail when a member of a moved value is assigned to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36048741/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. If you agree, you can mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Incidentally, your closure doesn't need to be a reference. You could just do `let c = move || /* ... */; (c)();`